# Feign focus in Selenium chrome browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium to scrape data from a website. The website requires window focus in order to display certain elements that I need.

I want to be able to run my program in the background, without having to focus the window while it's running.

Is there any way to trick the site into thinking it's focused on?

I'm using the selenium chrome driver.

---

Edit: [Here's a quick and dirty test I built](http://anubiann00b.github.io/FocusTest/).

Check out the code [on GitHub](https://github.com/anubiann00b/FocusTest/blob/gh-pages/index.html)

The website background color will turn black when the `window.onblur` event is recieved, and turn back white when the `window.onfocus` event is recieved.

I want to fake those events, to make the browser think it's recieved a focus event.

Comment: how your website understand that window is focused? Can you cheat that logic? What if you manually call javascript `focus` \ `click` methods on needed elements?

Comment: That's my question. Can I make the browser think it's focused?

Comment: it depends how is your web site determines that window is focused :) one of the way is to track focus\blur events of the `window` object, and save that state somewhere in javascript. but it may be different on your site

Comment: Can I make elements think they're focused even when the chrome window is not focused?

Comment: You can try to call javascript code to focus it. There are two DOM object methods that may help - `click` and `focus`. But it may not work, but worth to try. Something like that: `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('comment-user').click()")` or `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('comment-user').focus()")`

Comment: Why dont you run Selenium with PhantomJSDriver? It is headless, and can navigate through pages/click elements/scrape, also the process will run in the background just like you want. For python, its probably Ghost.py.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I got a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the page gets focus information through the `onfocus` and `onblur` callbacks in the `window` object, you can just call them yourself.

```
browser.execute_script("window.onfocus()")
browser.execute_script("window.onblur()")
```

For fun, try this script out:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriver)

browser.get('http://anubiann00b.github.io/FocusTest/')

while True:
    browser.execute_script("window.onfocus()")
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.execute_script("window.onblur()")
    time.sleep(1)
```

And of course, if you want to make the browser think it's always focused, make the `onblur` method call the `onfocus` method:

```
browser.execute_script("window.onblur = function() { window.onfocus() }")
```