# Selenium - Unable to Immitate OnFocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, selenium

Using Splinter (Selenium wrapper), I'm attempting to load an iFrame that is triggered by the window's visibility. The iFrame only loads on the web page when the browser window is in the foreground of my monitor. If another window is blocking it (or is in a different workspace), the iFrame will not load.

I want to force Selenium to always think it is in focus. I'm trying to do this via javascript:

```
browser.execute_script("window.onblur = function() { window.onfocus() }")
```

However, this still doesn't load the iFrame. I'm Javascript illiterate, but [this is the code](https://codeshare.io/5zvPBN) that I believe decides when to show the captcha iframe. The piece of `code window.onblur = function() { window.onfocus() }` was recommended [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734701/feign-focus-in-selenium-chrome-browser).

I've also tried:

```
browser.execute_script("window.focus();")
```

and variations of:

```
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('THING').focus();")
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('THING').click();")
```

Comment: Of-coarse `force Selenium to always think` is not equivalent to implementing `window.onfocus()`. Do you want to regain _Browser focus_?

Comment: @DebanjanB Regaining focus would be perfectly find if it let me load the iframe. I've tried browser.execute_script("window.focus();") -- which I thought would regain browser focus, but it did not.

Comment: I am still not sure what makes you feel **focus()** is the issue here. I feel the issue is somewhere else which you are unable to diagnose. Update the question with your __Automation Steps, _code trials_ and relevant _HTML_.